# What is $C,$ when it gets square rooted in this differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question regarding a function relating to time concerning my constant.
It starts of with:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}= \frac{-\sqrt{y}}{24}$$

$$-24\int y^{-1/2} \, dy=0\,dt$$

$$y^{1/2} = \frac{-t+c}{48}$$

Here's the part I'm tripping up on. I tried squaring the whole equation and began to expand my RHS, getting

$$y= \frac{t^2}{48^2}-\frac{2tc}{48^2}+\frac{c^2}{48^2}$$

At $y(0)=1,$

$$1= \frac{c^2}{48^2}$$

$$\pm 48 = c$$

So.. how do I know what $c$ is? is it $48$ or $-48$?

Moreover, I'm trying to find $y(t)=0,$ so

$$0= \frac{t^2}{48^2}-\frac{2tc}{48^2}+\frac{c^2}{48^2}$$

Multiplying both sides by $48^2$ gives

$0=t^2-2tc+c^2$, and when $c$ equals to plus/minus, both of my answers are different so I don't know what to do with $C$

Answer (score 2):

You need not expand the equation in order to find $c$.

You have $\sqrt t = \frac{-t +c }{48}$ and $y(0) = 1$, so substituting this you get $1 = c/48$ and $c = 48$.

If you have the initial condition $y(a) = 0$ then you get $c = a$.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}\dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d t}&=\dfrac{-\surd y}{24}\\[1ex]\displaystyle\int\dfrac{-1}{2\surd y}\mathrm d y&=\int \dfrac{1}{48}\,\mathrm d t\\[1ex]\surd y&=\dfrac {t+c}{48}\end{align}$

So when $t=0$ and $y=1$, we have $48\surd 1=(0+c)$, so $c=48$.

Then $y(t)=0$ when $0=t+ 48$, so...

Comment: But how can time (t) be a negative number though?

Comment: It's a time that comes before the time you call $0$.